# Export SQLPluse Query from Oracle to CSV with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: oracle, encoding, character-encoding, sqlplus

I am using the below SQLPluse Script to export data out of Oracle into CSV files. The issue is I need the files to be in UTF-8 and its currently ANSI. How do i go about getting the files to be UTF-8?

```
SET colsep ';'
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 800
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET NUMW 50



column timecol new_value timestamp
column spool_extension new_value suffix
SELECT '.csv' spool_extension
FROM dual;
/


SPOOL C:\job_files\production\Data_Upload\TEST_1&&suffix
@@"C:\job_files\production\Data_Upload\TEST_1";
/


Exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear from your question what you mean, but I assume the issue is the data your query returns contains UTF8 data but your output does not show the UTF8 characters correctly.

The NLS_LANG environment variable controls how Oracle tools/programs including SQL*Plus handle such data.

You would normally set the variable to something that matches the database, e.g

`export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

Then run SQL*Plus.

You can query `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` to see what language settings are in the database and experiment with the NLS_LANG variable as above.

NLS_LANG value format is `LANGUAGE_COUNTRY.CHARSET`.